# how to view UDF grants in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Team, 
could you help me to get the sql query to find out below :

1) I grant "USAGE ON LANGUAGE PLPYTHONU" to TESTUSER1 on database TESTDB1. How to find out whether this user has this permission granted in that specific DB testdb1 ?

```
testdb1=>grant USAGE ON LANGUAGE PLPYTHONPU to testuser1;
```

2) I grant execute permission on one function to TESTUSER1. how to find whether this user has this permission granted in that specific db testdb1 ?

```
testdb1=> grant execute on function schema1.fun1(float,float) to testuser1;
GRANT
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

1) How to check the permissions for `USAGE ON LANGUAGE PLPYTHONU`

```
select lanname,lanacl from pg_language where lanname = 'plpythonu';
```

`lanacl` contains the user name if the permission is given.

ex)

```
dev=# select lanname,lanacl from pg_language where lanname = 'plpythonu';
  lanname  |                    lanacl
-----------+----------------------------------------------
 plpythonu | {rdsdb=U/rdsdb,my_test_user=U/rdsdb}
(1 row)
```

2) How to check the permissions for `EXECUTE ON FUNCTION`

```
SELECT proname,proacl FROM pg_proc WHERE proname='<function-name>'
```

`proacl` contains the user name if the permission is given.

ex)

```
dev=# SELECT proname,proacl FROM pg_proc WHERE proname='f_greater';
  proname  |                                        proacl
-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 f_greater | {=X/admin,admin=X/admin,my_test_user=X/admin}
(1 row)
```

Unfortunately, it looks like there is no convenient default macro to get those kind of info nicely. Since there is no notion of databases for `LANGUAGE` or UDF, you don't need to specify the database name in those queries.